# Read from file two lines at a time

Tags: c, client-server, fopen, fgets

I'm trying to create a simple server that can connect to many clients and return to them a quote (two lines) from a file that is passed into the server.  I've had no trouble with connecting the client and server or opening the files, but I'm having a little trouble trying to get two lines at a time.  Every time the client requests a quote, the server should read the next two lines from the file and send them to the client.  When the server reaches the end of the file, it should reset back to the top of the file.  Can anyone help me out with this?

**UPDATE:  Here is what I am currently doing to get two lines at a time, I just am not sure how to check if it's at the end of file and if so, go back to top of file.  Any help on that?**

line is the character array I'm sending and einstein is the open file that I'm reading from.

```
i=0;
while (i<2)
{
    char temp[256] ;
    fgets(temp, sizeof(temp), einstein) ;
    strcat(line, temp) ;
    i++;
}

send(sock, line, strlen(line), 0 ); /* write the line */

strcpy(line, "") ;
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have the code which is not working?

Comment: Yes, please provide a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: my current code returns some random amount of lines, and I know that it shouldn't work as it, I just am not sure how exactly to make it work, but I'll add the portion that I'm referring to

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple helper function:

```
char *read_next_line(char *buffer, size_t size, FILE *file)
{

   if (fgets(buffer, size, file))
   {
       return buffer;
   }
   // error or EOF
   if (!feof(file)) return NULL; // error
   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
   return fgets(buffer, size, file);
}
```

The function attempts to read the line, if it fails, it tries to reposition the stream and read again.

So the code would look like:

```
FILE *list = fopen("config.txt", "r"); 
char line[1024];

if (read_next_line(line, sizeof(line), list)
{
    send(sock, line, strlen(line), 0);
    if (read_next_line(line, sizeof(line), list)
    {
       send(sock, line, strlen(line), 0);
    }
}
```

An alternative can look like:

```
FILE *list = fopen("config.txt", "r"); 
char line[2048]; // buffer for 2 lines

if (read_next_line(line, sizeof(line), list)
{
    size_t len = strlen(line)
    if (read_next_line(line + len, sizeof(line) - len, list)
    {
       send(sock, line, strlen(line), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a)
Use fseek to seek back to the top of the file before you close it.

int fseek(FILE *stream, long offset, int whence);

b) keep the file in a buffer in memory to send later?